# Is it possible to attach an event handler to SqlTransaction.Commit?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is it possible to attach an event handler to SqlTransaction.Commit?

I'm trying to track changes made in a control. When saved, I want to reset the flag, but, while the control handles saving, the transaction is passed and may or may not be rolled back later. So I need the flag to reset on transaction.commit. Any chance it's possible to tie some kind of event to the transaction's commit function while the control has it?

I've spent almost no time thinking about this, so if it all sounds like bad ideas, feel free to say "no, you're doing everything wrong. this question sucks"

Comment: You could create a proxy/wrapper around the IDbCommand or Transaction and add an event to it.